# If interface cannot have a constructor, what happens here?

Tags: java, interface

need some help on this, If interface cannot have a constructor, what happens here?

```
interface A{
     String toString(); 
}

public class B{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new A() {
           public String toString() { 
              return "what happens here!!"; 
           }
     });
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21325360/1686291 check out this SO answer.

Answer (score 10):

An instance of an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) implementing A is created.

This has very little to do with constructors, except that the default no-arg constructor will be called, and the `toString()` method is already defined in the Object class, so the interface is superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(new A() {
     public String toString() { return "what happens here!!"; }
  });
}
```

can be more explicitly rewritten as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   class ImplA() extends Object implements A {
     public ImplA() { super(); }
     public String toString() { return "what happens here!!"; }
   }
   System.out.println(new ImplA());
}
```

From the above you can understand the following:

- the local class `ImplA` is a subclass of `Object` and also implements `A`;
- `Object` has a nullary constructor;
- `ImplA` defines a nullary constructor, which delegates to `Object`'s nullary constructor;
- the constructor thus declared is called when writing `new ImplA();`

Your version of code just employs Java's syntactic sugar which lets you combine  *local class declaration* with *class instantiation* into a single expression.